# how to find a object in rect or at point

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview

On a NSView there are many other NSViews and some of them are moving with keyboard scroll keys. when moving object come on top of any static one i want to get which object sits under moving one. with mouse this is easy however without mouse i couldn't find a way to achieve this.

Comment: That object what is? An image, a subview or what?

Comment: all of them are subview of a view.

Comment: Ok you use scroll keys but what criteria you want to use for "get which object sits under moving one", elaborate the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to loop through all of the views you want to test, get each view's frame, convert that rectangle to the relevant view's coordinate system (search for “convertRect:” in the NSView docs), and then use the geometry functions to [test whether the moving view's converted frame intersects](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSIntersectsRect) the static view's frame.

Answer (score -1):

This might help you

```
-(void)handleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    CGPoint tappedPoint = [gesture locationInView:self.view];
    NSLog("You tapped in on screen point : %@",tappedPoint);
}
```

Using this `tappedPoint` we can check that in which view's rect these points are present.

**Important** We have to add tap gesture in our view to use this function.

Comment: it is NSView which for OSX not IOS.